# Passing huge object from parent to child component

Tags: angular, refactoring, parent-child, ngfor

I am refactoring a code where I want to pass down several properties to a reusable child component -- but without using too many inputs (which is the current problem).

The problem is that, even with my current approach, the html code looks shabby because of passing down a huge object (below is just an example. The object can be bigger since there are many properties to be passed to child).

My code looks something like below:

```
<app-parent>
<ul>
  <li
    *ngFor="let prop of props"
    <app-child
    [childProps]="{'template':'parent1', 'iconName':prop.type | propIcon, 'showIcon':true}"
  >
    </app-child>
  </li>
</ul>
</app-parent>
```

Is there an alternative approach that follows best practices and at the same time makes the code more readable?

Comment: So what's your question? You don't like the 'shabby' code? You're concerned about the size of the object? Something else?

Comment: I would say it's both. I'm looking for a solution in terms of best practices and that also makes the code more readable. What is your opinion of my current approach?

Answer (score 1):

In component.ts create a new mapped array:

```
let mappedProps: ChildProp[] = props.map((prop) => ({
   ...prop, // Make sure all values from the old props array are here as well
   template: 'parent1',
   showIcon: true
}));
```

Afterwards in component.html:

```
<app-parent>
<ul>
  <li
    *ngFor="let prop of mappedProps"
    <app-child [childProp]="prop">
    </app-child>
  </li>
</ul>
</app-parent>
```

Notice I changed the child input value to `childProp` since you are only passing one object down there, not an array

Comment: This is a nice solution but I doubt if I can modify the *ngFor, since there are other places in html that make use of prop (not shown in question snippet). If I disturb that, then I'm afraid some part of the code might break.

Comment: In this case, you can have all the values of prop in mappedProps as well, with my edited answer